# How to make AzureCLI@2 ignore the result of "az keyvault certificate delete"?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template, azure-cli

In an Azure pipeline for nightly builds, I am performing the following steps:

- deploy a keyvault by an ARM template,
- then try to delete a self-signed cert in it,
- then import the cert again -
- and finally deploy a service fabric by another ARM template, using the cert by the thumbprint.

Here is an extract of the pipeline:

```
# purge the self-signed cert from the Keyvault to avoid conflict; ignore failures (DOES NOT WORK?)
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.ArmConnection }}'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    continueOnError: true
    failOnStandardError: false
    powerShellErrorActionPreference: 'silentlyContinue'
    inlineScript: |
      az keyvault certificate delete --vault-name $(KeyVaultName) --id 'https://$(KeyVaultName).vault.azure.net/certificates/my-self-signed-cert'
      az keyvault certificate purge --vault-name $(KeyVaultName) --id 'https://$(KeyVaultName).vault.azure.net/deletedcertificates/my-self-signed-cert'

# import the self-signed certificate my-self-signed-cert into the Keyvault
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.ArmConnection }}'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    azurePowerShellVersion: '3.1.0'
    Inline: |
      $Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'MyPassword' -Force -AsPlainText
      $Base64 = 'MIIKqQI__3000_CHARS_HERE____HP1ICAgfQ=='
      $Cert = Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $(KeyVaultName) -Name my-self-signed-cert -CertificateString $Base64 -Password $Pwd
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Thumbprint;isOutput=true]$Cert.Thumbprint"
```

At first the above code was working for, but then I have disabled *soft delete* feature in the ARM template for the keyvault:

```
"properties": {
    "enableSoftDelete": false,
    "enabledForDeployment": true,
    "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
    "enabledForTemplateDeployment": true,
```

Or maybe the trigger for my problem was just deleting the keyvault by hand...

Anyway now I get the repeated pipeline errors:

[image: pipeline screenshot]

I wonder why is "az" failure not ignored, despite me setting `failOnStandardError: false` and `powerShellErrorActionPreference: 'silentlyContinue'`?

Also, I tried surrounding both "az" commands by a "try / catch", but the error is still there:

```
##[debug]which 'az'
##[debug]found: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd'
##[debug]scriptType=pscore
##[debug]scriptLocation=inlineScript
##[debug]scriptArguments=null
##[debug]powerShellErrorActionPreference=silentlyContinue
##[debug]Agent.Version=2.169.0
##[debug]Agent.TempDirectory=d:\a\_temp
##[debug]scriptPath=d:\a\1\s
##[debug]inlineScript=az keyvault certificate delete --vault-name my-nightly-my-keyvault --id 'https://my-nightly-my-keyvault.vault.azure.net/certificates/my-self-signed-cert'
 --vault-name my-nightly-my-keyvault --id 'https://my-nightly-my-keyvault.vault.azure.net/deletedcertificates/my-self-signed-cert'
##[debug]powerShellIgnoreLASTEXITCODE=false

...lines skipped...

A certificate with (name/id) my-self-signed-cert was not found in this key vault. If you recently deleted this certificate you may be able to recover it using the correct recovery command. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125182
Operation "purge" is not enabled for this vault.
##[debug]$LASTEXITCODE: 1
##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe'
##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe'
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Script failed with exit code: 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Script failed with exit code: 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Script failed with exit code: 1
##[debug]which 'az'
##[debug]found: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd'
##[debug]which 'az'
##[debug]found: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd'
##[debug]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd arg:  account clear
##[debug]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd arg:  account clear
##[debug]exec tool: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd
##[debug]exec tool: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd
##[debug]arguments:
##[debug]arguments:
##[debug]   account
##[debug]   account
##[debug]   clear
##[debug]   clear
[command]C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd" account clear"
##[section]Finishing: AzureCLI
```

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? Please check if my answer helps :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround adding `exit 0` has helped me -

```
# purge the self-signed cert from the Keyvault to avoid conflict; ignore failures (DOES NOT WORK?)
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.ArmConnection }}'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    continueOnError: true
    failOnStandardError: false
    powerShellErrorActionPreference: 'silentlyContinue'
    inlineScript: |
      az keyvault certificate delete --vault-name $(KeyVaultName) --id 'https://$(KeyVaultName).vault.azure.net/certificates/my-self-signed-cert'
      az keyvault certificate purge --vault-name $(KeyVaultName) --id 'https://$(KeyVaultName).vault.azure.net/deletedcertificates/my-self-signed-cert'
      exit 0
```

And then I have got [a better answer at Github](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13001) to use [ignoreLASTEXITCODE: true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#ignore-last-exit-code) or for the AzureCLI task (which is my case) to use `powerShellIgnoreLASTEXITCODE: true`

Comment: Good job ! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check your yaml format. `continueOnError` is not input of the task, instead it's one property of the task itself. So your task should be:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xxx'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    failOnStandardError: false
    inlineScript: |
      az keyvault certificate delete --vault-name $(KeyVaultName) --id 'https://$(KeyVaultName).vault.azure.net/certificates/my-self-signed-cert'
      az keyvault certificate purge --vault-name $(KeyVaultName) --id 'https://$(KeyVaultName).vault.azure.net/deletedcertificates/my-self-signed-cert'
    powerShellErrorActionPreference: 'silentlyContinue'
  continueOnError: true
```

If the property works, your subsequent tasks would continue to execute though the error is thrown in `Azure CLI task`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying (upvoted by me), however the solution for my case turned out to be the  `powerShellIgnoreLASTEXITCODE: true`